# Linked Static Libraries are NOT Rebuilt Together with Main Project

Tags: ios, xcode

In my workspace I have 2 projects: my main project, and a static library project. I link the resulting `.a` of the library project into the main project. Problem is, when I make a change to a source file in the library project, and run the main project, **the library project does not get rebuilt, and the old `.a` library gets used**. This leads to strange runtime errors.

Is there a way to enable correct compilation of dependency projects?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Xcode there for ages.

Workaround:

1. In Project Navigator find the reference to the library .a file in the **main project**.
2. In Utilities pane, change to "Relative to Build Products"
3. Edit `project.pbxproj` and find the line the static library `lib*.a`
   file is referenced by `"path=..."`.
4. Remove the path, so just `lib*.a` is left.